# Storing a photo in Laravel. Migration file's structure

Tags: image, laravel, migration, database-migration

I'm creating a table to hold multiple photos a user uploads through a form. I was told to

> you'd need to create a separate table for them (photos) create a separate model (Photo with a field 'src')

My issue is with the src. Do i need to save a property of the table as a src
so instead of `$table->string('photo);`

its

```
$table->src('photo);
```

Answer (score 3):

you will need to define migrations like these.

In your photo table migration follow this:

```
 Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id'); //you save this id in other tables
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('src');
        $table->string('mime_type')->nullable();
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('alt')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

FYI the photo's model would look like this:

```
class Photo extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'src', //the path you uploaded the image
    'mime_type'
    'description',
    'alt',
  ];
}
```

In Other table migration:

```
 Schema::table('others', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('photo_id')->references('id')->on('photos');
 });
```

**Other** model which has relationship with photo

```
class Other extends Model
{

 public function photo()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class,'photo_id');
 }

}
```

Comment: do i need a src in the advert table. (The one that has a relationship to a photo)

Comment: .What should I do in my controller. I'm already saving an advert through a form, so how should i add the the photo_id to the main table. I get the error when migratting photo_id does not exist in table